# Local pick up only

Tags: shipping

We offer a variety of items for sale in our website. There are some that we do not want to offer the option for shipping instead we want to offer them for local pick up only. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. add a new attribute to the product to define which product can only be picked up locally
2. add a new shipping method (or just use e.g. `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Pickup`)
3. Manipulate the output of `\Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::_getShippingMethodsHtml`

   - I didn't find an event anywhere, so either you manipulate the xml config array before the shipping methods are loaded - which is quite dirty

     somewhore down here: `\Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRates` or `\Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectCarrierRates`
   - or you manipulate the output afterwards, somewhere around here:

     ```
     // \Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::_getShippingMethodsHtml
     $layout->generateBlocks();
     $output = $layout->getOutput();
     ```
   - or you manipulate everything in the template which is a bad technique too, but I think the best of the three...

     ```
     checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml
     ```

And after implementing the showing and choice for the customer you have to check, that he didn't fool you, so check the input. But this is easy now, because in `\Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveShippingMethodAction` there is an event for this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent(
    'checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
    array(
        'request'=>$this->getRequest(),
        'quote'=>$this->getOnepage()->getQuote()
    )
);
```

I have no idea how to transport an error message to the front via this ajax call but I'm sure you'll figure it out :-)

And a list tipp: If the user has a mixed order, you should add a message, so he knows if he removes XXX from the cart it can be sent.